# onCreateContextMenu in two lists

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, fragment

I'm using a sherlock lib and I have a SherlockBar + ViewPagerIndicator with 2 SherlockListFragment, I need to use `onCreateContextMenu` in each list, I wrote a oveeride method in main `extends SherlockFragmentActivity`

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo contextMenuInfo) {
    if(indicator.getCurrentItem()==PAGE_M) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mcontextmenu, contextMenu);
        messageViewHolder=(MessageViewHolder )view.getTag();
    }
    else {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.ccontextmenu, contextMenu);
        messageViewHolder=null;
    }
    super.onCreateContextMenu(contextMenu, view, contextMenuInfo);
}
```

, but context menu works only in first list. Where is my mistake?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure to call registerForContextMenu inside onActivityCreated for each fragment .

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedState) {
registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}
```

Comment: the problem is that context menu is registered only for first fragment, I tried to onCreateContextMenu in each fragment. but its not helped